Parameter estimation of Heston model for VaR using Maximum Likelihood
I found an article file that explains how to estimate the parameters of the Heston model. I want to use the parameter results to calculate the value at risk. However, after reading it, I realized that the estimation can only be done for option pricing, not for value at risk. Could you highlight the part that shows the method or explain it to me? Thank you.
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304405X06001395
(Yacine Ait-Sahalia & Robert Kimmel, 2007, Maximum likelihood estimation of stochastic volatility models)

Your link doesn't work for me but I guess you refer to Yacine Ait-Sahalia and Robert Kimmel's 2007 JFE paper "Maximum likelihood estimation of stochastic volatility models"?

Yes it is correct

Yes that is correct. I'm only interested in the values of the model parameters under the physical probability measure P.

You can use the Heston model for VaR! In fact, you can calculate quantiles of your distribution easily with that model. In the end, the Heston model is (somewhat) similar to a continuous time GARCH model. I'd suggest using MLE or GMM to estimate the model parameters. Note that they'll change over time and across frequencies etc.

Yes, but I don't understand how to estimate parameters under the physical probability measure P, which is used to calculate VaR

I suggested two estimators: MLE or GMM. We know the moment generating function for the Heston model. From that, you can recover the likelihood function (MLE) or calculate a number of moments (GMM). Both estimators will give you estimates for the model parameters as well as standard errors etc

Do you have any other references related to that?

Risk analysis i.e. VaR and CVaR typically use GARCH models and its variations for analysis since we are dealing with real-world measures. As you correctly concluded, GARCH and SV models aren't used for the same thing, the latter being for derivative pricing. The standard approach that is taught in risk management handbooks e.g.
Quantitative Risk Management: Concepts, Techniques and Tools - Revised Edition, teach GARCH because GARCH is accurate in measuring historical volatility, which can be used for forward simulations to give risk levels. Using historical volatility has validity since volatility behaviour is reasonably consistent for each asset, i.e. the volatility of oil will have a lot more shocks compared to treasury bills for reasons that are unique to the asset.
If you want to do risk-analysis, the simple approach would be to take historical data of your chosen asset(s), calibrate a GARCH model using either frequentist inference (MLE) or bayesian inference (MCMC), then use the calibrated model to run forward monte-carlo simulations and calculate your expected-shortfall and VaR.
The are a plethora of different models that are used for risk management with their own strengths and weaknesses , but the general theme is that you are modelling volatility, and you want to pick a model that has similar attributes to your problem.

So, does that mean I can't use the Heston Model to calculate VaR?

I mean, you can, but you could use any type of model and calculate your VaR. Some models are better than others for different instruments, market conditions and the data you have readily available. I am only pointing out the industry standard "base model," and generally stochastic volatility models aren't really used for risk-management (that I've seen or heard of)
